# How to remove javascript/jquery hover event from div located in script without access?

Tags: jquery, hover

Can anyone explain if it is possible to unbind a hover event added to an element from within a script I have no access to.
I can't just add pointer events none with css to it, since I do want to have a click event for this element.
Not able to use:

```
element{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This isn't working for me either:

```
$(element).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Any help is more then appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** the event was hooked via jQuery, you can remove it like this:

```
$(element).off("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

That removes **all** jQuery-hooked `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the element. More in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off).

Why `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`? Because the [`hover` documentation tells us](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for:
>
> ```
> $( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
> ```

---

If the handler **wasn't** hooked up with jQuery, but was hooked up with the DOM's `addEventListener` (or Microsoft's `attachEvent`), you can't remove the handler without having a reference to the handler function (and you can't get a reference to the handler function if you don't already have it).

You can effectively remove **all** handlers attached directly to the element by destroying the element and replacing it with an identical replacement. All modern browsers support `outerHTML`, which can be used for this purpose:

```
element.outerHTML = element.outerHTML;
// or with More! jQuery!(tm)
$(element).replaceWith(element.outerHTML);
```

It looks like a no-op, but it isn't one. It completely destroys the element (and all of its children), thereby disconnecting all handlers on them, and then recreates new, mostly-identical elements. (Some state information, particularly in `select` elements, may get lost.)

Example:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  console.log("mouseenter triggered");
}, false);
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function(e) {
  // Destroy and recreate
  $(target).replaceWith(target.outerHTML);
  console.log("Now, the mouseenter handler won't work anymore");
});
```

```html
<div id="target">Mouse over me</div>
<input type="button" value="Click to destroy and recreate">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, for some reason this isn't working either, would this also remove plain javascript hover events, no inline script though. An id of active is being added on hover.
Also tried removing this id on hover, with removeAttr('id'), and even if my script is loaded afterwards it doesn't seem to influence.

Comment: @asturnick: *"...would this also remove plain javascript"* You mean plain DOM (JavaScript is a language, not an API). No, that's why I said "if". You can't remove a DOM event handler if you don't have a reference to the handler function, except by actually destroying the DOM element and then replacing it with a new, identical one, which removes *all* handlers (since they're attached to the old element).